# Why doesn't tsocks work with apt-get?

Tags: apt, proxy, socks5

I am using `tsocks` to socksify my connections. When I run the following commands, `apt-get` isn't socksified:

```
$ . tsocks -on
$ sudo apt-get update
```

However, when I run the whole thing in one line like the following, it works.

```
sudo tsocks apt-get update
```

I have verified that when I type `. tsocks -on`, my `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable is set to `/usr/lib/libtsocks.so`.

Why doesn't the former work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the answer given by @creveti-mihai, I looked at the `sudoers` man page. Unfortunately, as the man page says, it is not possible to preserve `LD_*` variables. Here is what the man page says:

> ```
>  Note that the dynamic linker on most operating systems will remove
>  variables that can control dynamic linking from the environment of setuid
>  executables, including sudo.  Depending on the operating system this may
>  include _RLD*, DYLD_*, LD_*, LDR_*, LIBPATH, SHLIB_PATH, and others.
>  These type of variables are removed from the environment before sudo even
>  begins execution and, as such, it is not possible for sudo to preserve
>  them.
> ```

So, I'll have to look at specifying the proxy in apt's own configuration files using `Acquire::http::proxy` and `Acquire::https::proxy`.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's already given an answer I want to share what worked for me, using Ubuntu 14.04:

`sudo apt-get install tsocks`

Then open /etc/tsocks.conf and add your server to server and port to server_port, also add your socks server's range as local, like


Example if your ip address is 90.70.60.5 then write:

`local = 90.70.60.0/255.255.255.0` (Note the .0 as the last part in ip address)


Now try:

`sudo tsocks apt-get update` (or whatever apt-get command) 

If it doesn't work using sudo, log in directly as root like: 

`sudo su`

Then try again:

`tsocks apt-get update`

I was behind a socks 5 server to reach a download link I didn't have access from my own computer, and it worked flawlessly.

**Note**: With this I didn't have to use "Acquire" stuff in /etc/apt/apt.conf

Answer (score 0):

Is the root's `LD_PRELOAD` also set to `/usr/lib/libtsocks.so`? Take a look at:

- The `-E` (preserve environment) option for `sudo`. Ex: `sudo -E bash -c 'echo $LD_PRELOAD'` vs `sudo echo $LD_PRELOAD`;
- The `sudoers` file: `Defaults env_keep`;

Comment: When I run the first command in your first option, I get nothing. However, running the second command in the first option gives me the output. I've also done `sudo -i` and then `echo $LD_PRELOAD`, and I've gotten nothing. So I assume the variable isn't being set when I run `. tsocks -on`. How can I make it be set though?

Comment: That is correct. Take a look at the manpage for `sudo` (look at the -E flag to preserve the environment) or the manpage for `sudoers` at `env_keep`).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure how I should do this. I've added `Defaults env_keep += "LD_PRELOAD"` to both `/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant` (the user with which I am sudo-ing) and `/etc/sudoers`, just beneath `Defaults env_reset`, but the first command in your first option, and also `sudo printenv LD_PRELOAD` still return nothing.